# Bad access in init

Tags: objective-c, realm

I am resurrecting an "old" Realm objective c project from 2018.
I have to admit I forgot all my objective c knowledge in the meantime and especially I am mentally completely off Realm (Unfortunately I cannot even say what my last realm version was, I guess it was 3.x. Now I updated to 4.3.0).

**I would be very grateful** if you could give me a hint if there happened some breaking changes to Realm so that my following code (which used to run fine) is crashing now.

I am getting BAD_ACCESS in the constructor of a RealmObject

```
@implementation TransformationParameters

- (instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil){
        [self reset]; // <--- BAD_ACCESS here ...
    }
    return self;
}
-(void) reset{
    self.rotation = 0.0; // <--- BAD_ACCESS here
    self.scale = 1;
    self.translationX = 0;
    self.translationY = 0.0;
}
```

and this is the corresponding header.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
@interface TransformationParameters : RLMObject
@property double translationX;
@property double translationY;
@property double scale;
@property double rotation;
-(CGAffineTransform) getAffineTransformForCIFilter:(CGSize)fullImageSize ;
-(CGAffineTransform) getAffineTransformForSKView:(CGSize)fullImageSize;
-(CGAffineTransform) getAffineTransformForUICombinationView:(CGSize)fullImageSize;

-(void) reset;
-(void) set:(TransformationParameters*) other;

@end
```

Here is the call stack:
[image: callstack xcode screenshot]

This code did run well since my last deploy on many devices.

I apologize if my question is stupid, please bear with me then.

Comment: Uh, I downgraded to Realm 3.21.0, and now it works.

Comment: I think you need `@property double rotation = 0.0;`. Could be wrong as my ObjC is a (lot) rusty as well.